# Bias and Variance term, in regards to bias Neural Network

Tags: variance, bias

I have recently been working with ANN, where I have come to the term of bias, which from my understanding is a constant value being added to the summation of weights and activation of previous neurons during training and backpropagation.

Previously I have introduced to the term `bias and variance`, in regards to `Linear Regression`, where `Variance` was described as the term, of the different fits from `training` data and `testing` data. Whereas low `bias`, meaning, that the model is not overfitting, and can handle different types of training samples.

Am I confusing these terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're conflating two usages of bias.

In the neural networks literature, "bias" is sometimes used to refer to adding a constant to a neuron.

In the broader statistical literature, "bias" (of an estimator) is used to describe the difference between an estimator's expected value and its true value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator